# spread columns and count by ID in r

Tags: r, dplyr, spread

I have a factor column that name is `Lead_DataSource__c`. I want to spread into one column for each factor and then fill the gaps by the count of that factor appears for every row by id.

Here is head of my dataframe;

```
head(df)


 Id                 Lead_DataSource__c numberoflead leadduration  lasttouch firsttouch
  <chr>              <chr>                     <int> <drtn>        <chr>     <chr>     
1 0010I000026fxp6QAA NA                            1       NA days NA        NA        
2 0010I000026frM6QAI Walk in                       1   0.0000 days Walk in   Walk in   
3 0010I000026frOQQAY Walk in                       1   0.0000 days Walk in   Walk in   
4 0010I000026frsUQAQ Walk in                       3 243.9656 days Walk in   Facebook  
5 0010I000026frsUQAQ Facebook                      3 243.9656 days Walk in   Facebook  
6 0010I000026frsUQAQ Facebook                      3 243.9656 days Walk in   Facebook
```

and I need this;

```
            Id lastcreateddateoflead lasttouch firsttouch Facebook Walk.in <NA>
            1 0010I000026frM6QAI                 43575   Walk in    Walk in        0       1    0
            2 0010I000026frOQQAY                 43843   Walk in    Walk in        0       1    0
            3 0010I000026frsUQAQ                 43794   Walk in   Facebook        2       1    0
            4 0010I000026frsUQAQ                 43794   Walk in   Facebook        2       1    0
            5 0010I000026frsUQAQ                 43794   Walk in   Facebook        2       1    0
            6 0010I000026fsBrQAI                 43699  Facebook   Facebook        1       0    0
```

I have tried this so far using dplyr but I didnt get what I want as seen above;

```
df%>%
group_by(Id,Lead_DataSource__c) %>%
 mutate(numberofleadsource=n()) %>% 
  spread(Lead_DataSource__c,numberofleadsource,fill = 0)
```

and this is the output of my codes;

```
             Id lastcreateddateoflead lasttouch firsttouch Facebook Walk.in <NA>
             1 0010I000026frM6QAI                 43575   Walk in    Walk in        0       1    0
             2 0010I000026frOQQAY                 43843   Walk in    Walk in        0       1    0
             3 0010I000026frsUQAQ                 43794   Walk in   Facebook        2       0    0
             4 0010I000026frsUQAQ                 43794   Walk in   Facebook        2       0    0
             5 0010I000026frsUQAQ                 43794   Walk in   Facebook        0       1    0
             6 0010I000026fsBrQAI                 43699  Facebook   Facebook        1       0    0
```

> 

Could anyone help me about what I m missing here?

### input data:

```
structure(list(Id = c("0010I000026fxp6QAA", "0010I000026frM6QAI", 
"0010I000026frOQQAY", "0010I000026frsUQAQ", "0010I000026frsUQAQ", 
"0010I000026frsUQAQ"), Lead_DataSource__c = c(NA, "Walk in", 
"Walk in", "Walk in", "Facebook", "Facebook"), numberoflead = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L), leadduration = structure(c(NA, 0, 0, 243.9656, 
243.9656, 243.9656), class = "difftime", units = "days"), lasttouch = c(NA, 
"Walk in", "Walk in", "Walk in", "Walk in", "Walk in"), firsttouch = c(NA, 
"Walk in", "Walk in", "Facebook", "Facebook", "Facebook")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please `dput(head(df,30))` and paste the output in your question in order to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I used `add_count()` to count how many times each ID/lead source combination occurred, and then `pivot_wider()` to spread it out. The last line fills in the missing values form the pivot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
       
df %>%
  add_count(Id, Lead_DataSource__c) %>%
  mutate(tmp = 1:nrow(.)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Lead_DataSource__c, values_from = n) %>%
  select(-tmp) %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate_at(c("NA", "Walk in", "Facebook"), ~ifelse(any(!is.na(.)), .[!is.na(.)][1], 0))
# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Groups:   Id [4]
  Id                 numberoflead leadduration  lasttouch firsttouch  `NA` `Walk in` Facebook
  <chr>                     <int> <drtn>        <chr>     <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 0010I000026fxp6QAA            1       NA days NA        NA             1         0        0
2 0010I000026frM6QAI            1   0.0000 days Walk in   Walk in        0         1        0
3 0010I000026frOQQAY            1   0.0000 days Walk in   Walk in        0         1        0
4 0010I000026frsUQAQ            3 243.9656 days Walk in   Facebook       0         1        2
5 0010I000026frsUQAQ            3 243.9656 days Walk in   Facebook       0         1        2
6 0010I000026frsUQAQ            3 243.9656 days Walk in   Facebook       0         1        2
```